# App engine datastore and Java low-level api: fetch multiple entities by its ids

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm with app engine and using the java low level api, and I want to retrieve a group of entities having its ids. What's the way to do so? I could fetch one by one but there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#get(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)), specifically in the following overload:

```
java.util.Map<Key,Entity> get(java.lang.Iterable<Key> keys)
```

to which you pass any iterable collection of `Key`s and get back a map from those keys (more precisely, the subset of those keys that do correspond to entities) onto the corresponding entities.  (To make a `Key` from an `id` you use a [KeyFactory](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.html) -- various `createKey` overloads, depending on parent or no parent). Back to `get`, there's a transactional overload for it too, if you do need to work in a transaction.